# Flutter - Change color of selected text in a Textfield

Tags: flutter, text, themes, textfield, selected

I have a Searchbar and due to my app theming, the text inside becomes hard to read when its selected. I would like to know if there is a way to set a different text color when it's selected.

[image: Searchbar]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [TextSelectionThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextSelectionThemeData-class.html)

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried with that and it doesn't give the option to change the selected text color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter does not support changing the selected text color via the theme declaration in the main widget, only can change background color. You must use the `SelectableText` in each input `style` property, like as:

```dart
SelectableText(
    'Example text',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // Yout text color on selected
)
```

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99231